# Hive PartitionFilter are not Applied

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I have facing this issue with hive.
When i Query a table ,which is partitioned on date column,
SELECT count(*) from table_name where date='2018-06-01' the query reads the entire table data and keeps for running  hours,
Using EXPLAIN I found that HIVE is not applying the PartitionFilter on the query
I have double checked that the table is partitioned on date column by desc table_name.

Execution engine is Spark And Data is stored in Azure Data lake in Parquet Format

However I have another table in the Database for which the PartitionFilter is applied and it executes as expected.

Can there be some issue with the hive metadata or it is something else

Comment: This issue was resolved by restarting the thrift-server.
When I Run the same query using spark-shell it execeuted as expected , Applying the PartitionFilter, So i restarted the thrift-server and checked again, The issue was solved
Still i didn't get the root cause of this issue. Hope someone can shed some light on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the cause for this issue,
Hive wasn't applying the Partition Filters on some table ,because those tables were cached.
Thus when i restared the thrift server the cache was removed and Partition Filters were applied